# how to add app engine bucket's urls to database java

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, bucket

but this code is working fine but only returns app engine bucket's uploaded files url? any idea of how to add the url into the database?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CloudStorageHelper  {
    Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\sachinthah\\Downloads\\MCQ project -1f959c1fc3a4.json"));
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

    public CloudStorageHelper() throws IOException {
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/imageUpload112")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("fileseee")MultipartFile fileStream)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String bucketName = "mcqimages";
        checkFileExtension(fileStream.getName());
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("-YYYY-MM-dd-HHmmssSSS");
        DateTime dt = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        String dtString = dt.toString(dtf);
        String fileName = fileStream.getOriginalFilename()  ;

        BlobInfo blobInfo =
                storage.create(
                        BlobInfo
                                .newBuilder(bucketName, fileName)
                                .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(User.ofAllUsers(), Role.READER))))
                                .build(),
                        fileStream.getInputStream()
                );
        System.out.println(blobInfo.getMediaLink());

        return blobInfo.getMediaLink()+",";
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what database are you talking about?I would like you to further elaborate since I don’t clearly understand what do you want to do.